# I am trying to manage a small number of users control of a webpage

Tags: javascript, sql-server, database, sqlite, raspberry-pi

So to start off, I have a raspberry pi, running a lighttp server on arch. I have a webpage that will have a max of 10 people connected at a time. Each user will be given the tag "Master," or "observer." The webpage will have controls that only the "Master," can use.

Just a heads up: I am just learning most of this so I may be making some mistakes about how to accomplish this.

My original idea is has follows. When a user connects to the database their IP address would be grabbed and inserted into a SQLite database, along with a user tag, and time of connection. From there I would be able to query the database for the users tag when they tried to execute various commands.

Whatever I use needs to be very lightweight and not store cookies on the users device.

Here is the JavaScript I currently have, it probably isn't the most efficient, but I plan on getting it working then making it look nice.

This code is supposed to connect the databases and insert the user.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    var db = openDatabase('userCon.contbl.sqlite', '1.0', 'contbl', 1024);
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
       var ip = myip;
       var conStatus = "master"
       var date = new Date();
       console.log('Inserting into the database ' + ip + ',' + conStatus +',' + date);
       transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO contbl(ipAd, conType, lastActive) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[ip,conStatus,date], function(transaction, results) {

       }, function (transaction, err){  
             console.log(err.message+":Error"); // here an error
          });
    });
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip">  </script>
```

I am unable to connect to the SQLite database I created on the pi, which  after my research may be because SQLite is supposed to be run locally and not on a server.

Is there some sort of work around to point to the SQLite database on the pi, or is there a better resource to use for this type of task?

EDIT:

I guess my original post was not specific enough. The basic idea is I need to be able to pass a tiny bit of information from a webpage, back to the server hosting it. i.e. User connect to the server and sends its IP then the server tags that IP as an Observer of Controller. From there the server will treat each person viewing the webpage differently based on how the user was tagged.

My original plan was to use a really light weight database like SQLite, but as I found out, SQLite is local use only. I need to do this on a sever with lower then 10 connections.

My hope is someone has a suggestion, or an example to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way for javascript running on a web page to talk to a server these days is some kind of RESTful web service.

You'll want to find a server-side programming language that runs on the Pi. Maybe node.js? It's like  javascript but on a server, see here: http://weworkweplay.com/play/raspberry-pi-nodejs/

You then write whatever methods you want in the server-side language, methods which talk to the database, then have your client-side javascript call those methods. Google "REST services node.js" and you'll find plenty of how-tos.

Answer (score 0):

If the SQLite database is running on the server, and this code runs in the user's browser, it can't connect to the database. The only interaction between the browser and your server is HTTP, unless there's a gigantic security hole in your server.

Comment: I made that point above, after I did more research into SQLite. I am trying to find a way to connect to the server now. The server wont be connected to the internet, so I dont mind a few holes. The pi is hosting its own network access point, so you can only get to the page if you are on the network.